# Try to extract font with Python or ImageMagick

Tags: python, fonts, imagemagick, cjk, rasterizing

I have a project, which converts text in Chinese to bitmap for remote LCD display. 'Cause it is running in server, command line tools are preferred.

I am trying to use Python/PIL and ImageMagick to implement such system. The ImageMagick is used to generate bitmap from text before Python/PIL converting it into a special packet format for remote displays.

After reading IM6 examples from IM website:

I found anti-alias makes troubles in the process. For example, it works great with following command:

`C:\ImageMagick-6.6.6-6\convert -background lightblue -fill blue -pointsize 48 -font "SimSun-&-NSimSun" label:@chinese_words.utf8 label_utf8_simsun.gif`

[Generated image](http://www.flickr.com/photos/47372045@N02/6936866806/in/photostream) Newbie is not allowed to post image.

It looks great because it has anti-alias with high resolution. The LCD has only B/W, no anit-alias, and it must be low resolution such as 12x12 pixel. I tried following script.

`C:\ImageMagick-6.5.6-Q16\convert -pointsize 16 -font "SimSun-&-NSimSun" +antialias -strokewidth 0.4 -threshold 50%% label:@chinese_words.utf8 label_utf8_simsun_16_bw_strokewid1.gif`

The result looks terrible, and bitmap pixel is missing.

[Generate Image](http://www.flickr.com/photos/47372045@N02/6936866850/in/photostream) Newbie is not allowed to post image.

Does anyone know how to extract the truetype font with Python/ImageMagick suitable for LCD (no anti-alias, two-color, small size/low resolution)?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

SimSun seems to be [well hinted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_hinting), so it's crisp and readable at small pixel sizes. The screenshot below is blown up from a character (I don't know what it is, so if it's something... rude, that wasn't my intention :) ) I pasted into WordPad at 10 pt font size in Windows 7.

[image: Screenshot of SimSun]

So: you might want to look into alternatives that render glyphs using a library that supports font hinting properly. FreeType does this (when compiled to have the hinting support in -- the algorithm is still patent-encumbered, if I remember correctly), and if your server platform will also be Windows, it will be fairly easy to write a C#/GDIPlus app that renders text for you.

**EDIT:** Out of curiosity and boredom I actually implemented cheap Python `ctypes` bindings to Freetype2 and added equally cheap rendering code following the Freetype2 tutorial. Seems to do a decent job even at small sizes -- and the hinting, etc. is tweakable, I'm just going with the defaults in my code.

[image]

The code is available at https://bitbucket.org/akx/python-minift/src -- I'm making no guarantees about it working like it should, but it's a decent starting point.

Comment: Thanks. Font hinting explains a lot. I am not sure about the OS of the production server, so a portable solution is preferred. For example, Python/PHP/GCC or similar. BTW, I am not good at Windows programming. As an alternative way, I find a native Chinese bitmap font back in DOS. It is easy to handle it with Python/C under Windows/Linux. However, unicode should be first choice, since my project is language independent, other languages should be supported including PanEuro/Korean/Japanese/Arabic/Farsi and etc. I will keep googling it.

Comment: @KaiLiu -- see my amended answer! :)

Comment: Cool. Thank you very much, it could be a good code base. Let me have a try.

Comment: Your URL is access denied. Maybe I don't have the privelige for that source.

Comment: @KaiLiu - I'm sorry, I had set the repository to be private. It's public now!

Comment: Thanks for your support. I have downloaded the source. I am trying it now.